# DFS: Print all complete paths

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

The Below function prints all the sub-paths. Is it possible to display only the complete paths i.e A->B->C (included REQUIRED OUTPUT below).

```
findPaths(List<Integer>[] adjacencyList, int u, List<String> path) throws IOException {
        print(path+" "+path.size()+ "\n");
        for (Integer v : adjacencyList[u]) {
            path.add(mapIndexToCode.get(v));
            findPaths(adjacencyList, v, path, writer);
            path.remove(mapIndexToCode.get(v));
        }
    }
```

```
OUTPUT
A 1
A B 2
A B C 3

E 1
E F 2
```

```
REQUIRED OUTPUT
A B C 3

E F 2
```

Comment: Well, think about the code logically. Why does it give you the output that it gives you? Can you think of something that is true whenever the `print` statement should run, and not true every time it should be suppressed? Can you think of a way in code to test for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition before printing to check if you are at the end of the path:

```
findPaths(List<Integer>[] adjacencyList, int u, List<String> path) throws IOException {
        if (adjacencyList[u].isEmpty()) {
           print(path+" "+path.size()+ "\n");
        }
        else {
        for (Integer v : adjacencyList[u]) {
            path.add(mapIndexToCode.get(v));
            findPaths(adjacencyList, v, path, writer);
            path.remove(mapIndexToCode.get(v));
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it printed the required output I wanted